# using lists in generator expressions with "target_link_libraries" command (unwanted -l flag)

Tags: cmake, ninja

I'm trying to use generator expressions to link imported libraries for my downstream builds. (using cmake 3.11.1 btw)

Since the generator command in TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES doesn't accept whitespace, I discovered I need to use the 'JOIN' command.  This seems to be adding an unwanted -l flag to my generated ninja file, however, and breaking the build.

```
# link dependencies
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(TGT1 
  "$<JOIN:$<$<BOOL:${DOWNSTREAM_PIPELINE}>:${IMPORTED_LIBS_FOR_TGT1}>, >")
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(TGT2 
  "$<JOIN:$<$<BOOL:${DOWNSTREAM_PIPELINE}>:${IMPORTED_LIBS_FOR_TGT2}>, >" $<TARGET_FILE:TGT1>)
```

the result in my Ninja file is:

```
LINK_LIBRARIES = -llibModuleA libModuleB libModuleC ...
```

What's going on here?

Thanks @StephenNewell for the hint.  Since the list had no spaces, I can use the BOOL generator expression.  I was just having problems with the quotes being in the wrong place.  The below works:

```
# link dependencies
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(TGT1 
  "$<$<BOOL:${DOWNSTREAM_PIPELINE}>:${IMPORTED_LIBS_FOR_TGT1}>")
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(TGT2 
  "$<$<BOOL:${DOWNSTREAM_PIPELINE}>:${IMPORTED_LIBS_FOR_TGT2}>" $<TARGET_FILE:TGT1>)
```

Comment: Do `IMPORTED_LIBS_FOR_TGT1` and `IMPORTED_LIBS_FOR_TGT2` contain spaces?

Comment: @StephenNewell it is a ;-list that I created using LIST(APPEND ...), no spaces.  I just checked with MESSAGE(). With quotes the list is ; delimited, without quotes there are no spaces.